# Unity referances not working Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

As seen in the image bellow, references are not showing up in visual studio.
I was just using visual studio and i closed the project opened some other project and opened the unity project again in visual studio.
But then none of the references shows up and i cant really fix it.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Unity Editor try:
`Edit -> Preferences... -> External Tools -> Regenerate project files`

Comment: And you need to choose VIsual Studio 2022 as an External Script Editor there

Comment: That option doesn't exist in "External tools"

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me, I couldn't solve it, I reinstalled visual again and downloaded c# plugins and module so it worked

Answer (score 0):

The code pair may not be able to compile due to not referencing the relevant library files and namespaces